# MySQL-python Cannot connect to server

Tags: python, mysql

This is driving me crazy.

I have Python 2.5 and MySQL-python-1.2.3 from the .exe available [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) installed on Vista.

I have been making `.php` pages over the past few weeks and connected fine in order to test them in my browser.

```
$dbcnx=@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword")
```

I have also been using mysql commandline with

```
mysql.exe -uroot -pmypassword just fine.
```

However, when I try to use MySQLdb with

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "mypassword")
```

I get

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

I have checked that MySQL is running in services.  I checked my MySQL config in my.ini and it is running on port=3306.  I have even uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL 5.1.  I read several pages of connection problems and answers on Google, but haven't yielded anything.  It must be something simple I am overlooking, but does anyone have any more ideas?

Comment: This is driving me crazy too ... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+connect+to+mysql

Comment: mind to double check the port ??? is default port 3306 or 10061?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use the windows version (all my relevant experience is on Linux), but I'd be willing to bet it will work if you use `127.0.0.1` in place of `localhost`.

Edit: -- a bit of explanation.

Firstly, check the entries in `mysql`.`user` table, for the `host` field (although by default, you probably have three entries for root which cover all bases).  Most likely, your problem is caused by the fact that the MySQL service is listening on 127.0.0.1:3306, not localhost:3306, and your `hosts` file or other routing config is not being invoked properly by the python interpreter.

Comment: WAH. I could have sworn I read of places where people said to change *to* using "localhost" from an address, so I never tried changing it to 127.0.0.1.  However, this seems to have worked!  (At least now it's returning an error with my MySQL syntax itself which I'll have to figure out.) I'm not exactly sure why it worked though, because looking at the mysql.user table, selecting host just gives back localhost.  Thank you so very much!  I should have asked earlier and saved myself 3 hours.

Comment: check the second part of my answer -- it will be to do with the routing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have opened the TCP port 3306 in your firewall for connections.

Also see this question [Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119008/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061)

Comment: Ah, I should have said I even went as far as disabling my firewall completely in an attempt to get this to work as well.  Thank you for the suggestion though.