# MySQL How to create connections consistently?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a connection in MySQL Workbench 5.6.  Currently I have two.  One connection works just fine.  The other throws the error  Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003).

What is the difference beteween the two?  The settings are the same between the two connections, so I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/q/119008/3132718 someone had similar problem. Does it help you in some way?

Comment: A little.  At least it gives me information, something other results I've found never did.