# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX' (111)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, host, digital-ocean

I have read up on the above error and from the way I understand, there could be many reasons that error pops up. I will try to be as specific as possible.

I have made a php file to do a simple database connect:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$servername = "188.166.***.***";
$username = "root";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "vod";
$con = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($con->connect_error){
    die("error ".$con->connect_error);
}
echo "success";
?>
```

When I run the above code I get the error:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX' (111)
```

When I enter `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` in the URL bar I am taken to the `index.html` file of the server. And when I enter `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/phpmyadmin` I am taken to phpmyadmin.

I hope I made my question clear.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the database server from your development machine or on your live site? If it is across the internet then it's almost certainly a firewall issue

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts , i hope it's help you.

Comment: @RamRaider The URL "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" is hosted on the internet and its not a local server

Comment: Avoid use root user  as a client side.. create new user use to access the database. Sometimes root is not a valid user and cant be use as client side. got that error sometime. then check permission.

Comment: @reds should the new user have all privileges

Comment: It depends on you. You can give as long as new user is allowed to do  according to your code.

Comment: @user3583252 you need to allow privilege to you ip address though cpanel or using CLI before using in your code

Comment: @aman how do I do that?

Comment: @user3583252 do you have access to your cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you if you want to do it like this:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'userpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

you can run it at your query database. just change user and password. good luck

Comment: Sir I made a new user and granted it all privileges and I still get the same error.

Comment: try to delete the user you made. then run this at your query. then we can check if error returns too.

Comment: check if mysql service is running too and check also network connectivity between server and database if separated.

Comment: I deleted the old user root and added a new one and I still get the same error. This might sound like a stupid question, but how do I check if MySQL service is running? I checked "services.msc" and the services "mysql" and "MySQL51" are both running on the local system. I checked task manager and mysqld is also running

Comment: and if network connectivity means internet, then thats working as well

Comment: it means your service is running. no problem to it. Please try to access and use your new user open your database manualiy at your DB UI with new user. just to test it.

Comment: check mysql port too.. the default is 3306

Comment: "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON %user.* to '%user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%user'"; run it

Comment: I have my XAMPP MySQL server running on Port 3306 so when I was using Query Browser I entered Port number 3307

Comment: can you access your db using new user? it must be 3306. coz your service running on 3306

Comment: No sir.. I'm still getting that same error on "MySQL Error Number 2003 Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (10061) " when I try to access the database

Comment: are you sure you only one mysql service using?

Comment: Right now I am using only the MySQL Server which was installed with XAMPP running on Port 3306. I can upload screenshots of my services.msc if needed

Comment: you mean you can't access your database totally even Workbench or something? are you using database on server(other pc) or localhost only

Comment: Nope. I can only access my database if I go to the URL: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx./phpmyadmin`

Comment: ok. It means you can modify everything as well.. that ip is not your's?It is a server ip i guess

Comment: is your system running on that server ip itself?

Comment: No sir. Its not the ip of my system. Its just the server that my php file is hosted on. Its not 127.0.0.1

Comment: yeah i know, but you can create and modify any user you want. am i ryt?

Comment: Yep. I can add user, remove user, modify privileges etc etc

Comment: how you do create a new user if you cant access your db as well? you said a while ago, you can't access your DB ryt?

Comment: Off to work for now, just check this hope it help to you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119008/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061

Comment: I can access my database if I go to the URL: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx./phpmyadmin` After I go to this URL I can make any changes I want