# Mysql server starts but can not connect network issue

Tags: java, mysql, database

I can see from running the 5.7 installer I have a running server.  When I go to run the --install I get 'Install/Remove of the Service Denied!'. I'd like to run the server and use the mysqlshow to see that I've installed the server correctly. Found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html and read through.

I've tried telnet to the localhost on port 330 and get:

```
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 330: Connect failed
```

When I look at what ports are open I don't see 330 listed at all.

I used mysqladmin and specified the port I'm on, I do get a list of the mysqladmin usage that looks like I could start writing to a table but I'm not connected to server so none of it works.  Tried to use the mysqlshow after that and got:

```
bin\mysqlshow: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

C:\MYSQL>bin\mysqld --console
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT 
value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server 
option (see documentation for more details).
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. 
Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [Note] bin\mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19) starting as 
process 3572 ...
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [ERROR] Can't find error-message file 
'C:\MYSQL\share\errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-
messages-dir' configuration directive.
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use 
Windows interlocked functions
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() 
are used for memory barrier
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 
1.2.3
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-07-24T16:17:23.646121Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 
instructions
2017-07-24T16:17:23.677544Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total 
size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-07-24T16:17:23.693017Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of 
buffer pool
2017-07-24T16:17:24.640166Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format 
is Barracuda.
2017-07-24T16:17:27.906296Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for 
temporary tables
2017-07-24T16:17:27.906296Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 
12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-07-24T16:17:30.117639Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 
MB.
2017-07-24T16:17:30.351854Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) 
found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-07-24T16:17:30.351854Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) 
are active.
2017-07-24T16:17:30.351854Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-07-24T16:17:33.071230Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated 
partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-
engine-check' to skip this check.
2017-07-24T16:17:33.071230Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively 
partitioned tables
2017-07-24T16:17:34.880009Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned 
tables
```

What do I do to be able to start writing mysql commands that can create the table(s) I need?

Comment: This link has the answer to the question being asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119008/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061

Comment: This is once I have created a database.  I am just trying to get the server connected before I can grant privileges to a table.

Comment: It's usually port 3306 not 330 that MySQL listens on.

Comment: Thanks I got this figured out.

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --install
```

If you don't run cmd as Administrator, **you'll see Install/Remove of service denied!**

So run the elevated command prompt(**Start->cmd->Run as Administrator**) to see the Service Successfully installed message.